# uinavigationbar behind status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

To explain with screen dumps:

[image: Before Modal]

User presses the button which launches a 3rd party compiled ViewController. This third party ViewController takes over entire screen and hides the status bar. Once user finished with it, they go back to the first screen (above), which ends up looking as this:

[image: AfterModal]

So far I've tried this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
}
```

But still I am unable to push down the initial UINavigationBar

=======================

Update:

I have fixed it using following:

```
CGRect frame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
frame.origin.y = 20;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = frame;
```

Would this work? Is Status bar always 20 height? I have tried reading status bar's height, but it returns 0...

Comment: Somewhere else in your navigation flow, do you hide either or both bars? I did that and observed the same issue when the bars were to re-appear. I do not remember exactly what eventually fixed it. I just remember that it nearly drove me crazy. It turned out to be a matter of animation, sequence and time. re-appearing the nav bar now happens in another method than re-appearing of the status bar. I think I separated them with `[self performSelector: ... with delay:...]` or so.

Comment: Status bar is not always 20px tall, for example when there is a phone call in the background.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg thanks for your input. I agree putting in 20px is not a solution. Still waiting for a Pro to reply :-)